# Can activerecord put user-defned sql in a from clause?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am attempting to build a "pull some data out and display it" app. To pull the data out, we have a great deal of site-specific oracle sql (stored procedures, weird expressions and whatnot).

One way of doing what I need to do is to create oracle views and then to point activerecord at those views. But I would rather have all the SQL in one place - the ruby app itself - rather than in oracle and ruby. I'd like to make an active record object over a raw SQL select clause, and then be able to use all the usual activerecord stuff with this.

Now - I know Oracle SQL supports this. Let's take:

```
select n.name_id, name, munge(n.name) as munged from name
```

Normally you'd create a view munged_name, a class MungedName, with the result that

```
MungedName.like(:name , 'Foo%')
```

would (eventually) generate SQL that looks like this:

```
select T1.name_id, T1.name, T1.munged 
from munged_name as T1
where T1.name like 'Foo%'
```

What I would like to do, however, is have ActiveRecord use the sql select as a subquery in the FROM clause:

```
select T1.name_id, T1.name, T1.munged
from (select n.name_id, name, munge(n.name) as munged from name) as T1
where T1.name like 'Foo%'
```

Just jam it in there literally - Oracle will optimise it perfectly ok. This way, all the weird queries that my people want to do are in the one spot - in the model class definition.

Will ActiveRecord do this? I'll keep looking - see if I can find out before I get an answer here :) .

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that passing that SQL fragment should work.

```
MungedName.from("select n.name_id, name, munge(n.name) as munged from name").like(:name , 'Foo%')
```

But you're probably looking for something even more Ruby-like, so you can of course generate that `from` fragment in Arel too:

```
sql = Name.select([:name_id, :name, "munge(name)"]).to_sql
MungedName.from(sql).like(:name , 'Foo%')
```

I did not try any of this from the command line. I have doubts that what I entered will work cleanly, but the idea is basically the same. Arel can be used to generate complex SQL, and have that SQL be fed into another Arel query.

I don't know for certain about the `from` part, but I suspect that will work as expected. If you check out the method source:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/a/arel-3.0.2/Arel/SelectManager.html#method-i-from

```
def from table
  table = Nodes::SqlLiteral.new(table) if String === table
  ...
end
```

The `SqlLiteral` class is just a way to bypass any quoting or whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code - it won't work. There is no self.from= method. When you jam raw sql in the table_name, it quotes that and treats it as though it were a table name. Which is fair enough. The activerecord ruby has a thing 'quoted_table_name' all the way through it.

There is, however, an intriguing comment on associations.rb:

```
# == Table Aliasing
#
# Active Record uses table aliasing in the case that a table is referenced multiple times
# in a join. If a table is referenced only once, the standard table name is used. The
# second time, the table is aliased as <tt>#{reflection_name}_#{parent_table_name}</tt>.
# Indexes are appended for any more successive uses of the table name.
```

If activerecord could be persuaded to always alias the MungedName model (even when there was no join), and to use some unquoted thingy as the content of the from, *that* might work. I'll have to hack up the library, though.